# how to redirect different Multiple pages using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

i was successfully redirected one page and its working fine, but when i am doing the same thing to other pages its not working. what is the best way to redirect and set url using htaccess with out effecting CSS, JS, IMG. bellow is my code which i used to redirect.

```
RewriteCond $1 ^ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search.php?loc=$1&q=$2 [L,QSA]


# Redirect to SEO Friendly Url search page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:search\.php)?\?loc=([^\s]+)&q=([^\s]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?loc=$1&q=$2 [L]
```

and my url is

```
https://www.zesteve.com/search.php?loc=Guntur&q=manjunath-cake-shop
```

its successfully changed to

```
https://www.zesteve.com/Guntur/manjunath-cake-shop
```

i don't to want my url show the page name `search.php`

now i am trying to change bellow url

```
https://www.zesteve.com/vendor.php?city=Hyderabad&type=bakers-and-confectioners&vname=manjunath-cake-shop&vid=87411490256961
```

to

```
https://www.zesteve.com/Hyderabad/bakers-and-confectioners/manjunath-cake-shop/87411490256961
```

with the bellow code

```
# Redirect to SEO Friendly Url Vendor page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:vendor\.php)?\?city=([^\s]+)&type=([^\s]+)&vname=([^\s]+)&vid=([^\s]+)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond $1 ^ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ vendor.php?city=$1&type=$2&vname=$3&vid=$4 [L,QSA]
```

its not working am i doing right way?

if any body not understand please leave a comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last rewrite rule you are capturing only one value but using `$1,$2,$3,$4` in your target.

Change your rules to this:

```
# Redirect to SEO Friendly Url Vendor page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:vendor\.php)?\?city=([^\s&]*)&type=([^\s&]*)&vname=([^\s&]*)&vid=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=301,NE,L]

# Redirect to SEO Friendly Url search page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:search\.php)?\?loc=([^\s&]*)&q=([^\s&]*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ vendor.php?city=$1&type=$2&vname=$3&vid=$4 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ /search.php?loc=$1&q=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: no change its pointing to previous page. URL is changed but vendor.php is not loaded.

Comment: It was because I had a trailing slash in pattern that should be optional. I updated my answer with full .htaccess so that you keep rules in this order only.

Comment: dose it work for 2 urls only or if i want to do the same thing to another url what should i change RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L] this is part was new to me.

Comment: Above set of rules work for `vendor.php` with 4 parameters and 2 parameters. If you need to support e.g. 3 parameters then add 2 similar (one with R=301 and another with internal rewrite) rules